# How to safely call a C++ function from Lua

Tags: c++, lua

I use [Sol2](https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2) in my project and I have some trouble running C++ functions from Lua. First of all, I binded some functions to lua via `sol::set_function()`. For example:

I have this function:

```
void PrintInt(int value){
    std::cout << "Something" << std::endl;
}
```

In my main I do this:

```
int main() {
    sol::state state;
    state.set_function("PrintInt", &PrintInt);
}
```

Now if I call function in Lua it works fine. But I have some situations in my game code which can produce some unexpected calls, like this one in Lua:

```
PrintInt(nil)
```

All code here is pseudocode, so doesn't matter how this happen. It can be, because Lua scripts are written by gamer. So question is how can I avoid this to happen? I don't want to force player write checks and etc.

I have checks in C++ at load and running script, but it doesn't provide me any error. I use `sol::protected_function_result` to check for errors. 
I tried to use `sol::optional`, but I got "Cannot find class '', to resolve delegate 'optional'".

Comment: Then write check yourself... what's the problem?

Comment: Don't tag in title.

Comment: What is SoI2? Can you give some background? If that's a Lua interop library, then I'd start by reading *its* documentation, which will surely specify the behaviour you're asking about.

Comment: [Repost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48444948/3484570).

Comment: @user202729, I can write checks, of course. My target is make simple user code without any "hard-to-understand" behavior like checking everything and etc.

@nwp, here is another problem, which connected with old one. Last question was about C++, but, as I found, problem in calling C++ function from Lua. As I understand, it works by function pointer. So, if we have `int (*pointer)(int)` and try call it with Lua's nil it's something scary. So, I think it's two different situations. And yes, my first question wasn't right: it was about consequences, but not about real reasons.

Comment: OMG, it works!
@KerrekSB, thank you very much! I don't know how, but last time I read docs, I skiped article about safety in running Lua code! Thank you again!

Comment: @Darell_Ldark: No problem, thanks for writing up the solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, thanks to comments and holy Sol2 docs!

Solution so easy and obvious: you just need to read this: [Sol2 Docs: config and safety](http://sol2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/safety.html).
After that just define any trigger you need like this:
`#define SOL_SAFE_USERTYPE 1`.
Your define should be in first place. After it you can include sol.hpp:

```
#define SOL_SAFE_USERTYPE 1
#include "sol.hpp"
```

That's all you should do.